# Win Server 2003 - Task Scheduler - Tasks with GUI and Services

Tags: windows

I need to run excel macro daily. I scheduled it with Windows Scheduler and it worked fine until I had to change my password. I wonder if it's possible to have a task scheduled without a password?

As alternative we have third party scheduling software, but this software cannot launch excel. The tech support said that since excel has gui and scheduling software runs as service with "Allow to interact to Desktop" disabled, it cannot launch excel. Also tech support mentioned that "Allow to interact to Desktop" is not supported as of Vista.

I totally trust tech support guy, I just need a work around that would make my network administrator and me happy.

Regards.

Comment: look into AutoIT scripting

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user on your machine, set the password to never expire, have the task run as that newly created account. That should make you and him both happy :)